# Splitting a text string into a int and text variable

Tags: python

I made a script to transfer information from my text files into my sql database, but I'm having a issue. The script I have split the text like this:

```py
for file in os.listdir("C:\\alt\\her"):
    if file:
        Array= file.split("_")
```

So this will split the string into an array like this `['Fieldbus', 'EtherNetIP', '848', '3217.txt']`
Then I make some variables with the info i get like this:

```py
Namearray = (Array[0]+"_"+Array[1])
JinkinsBuild = Array[2]
TestJob = Array[3].split(".txt")
```

So the output I get here is:

```py
>>>Namearray = Fieldbus_EtherNetIP
>>>JinkinsBuild = 719
>>>TestJob = 1926
```

This is perfect, but I have file names that looks like this:

`Fieldbus_EtherNetIP_719_1926`, `SZTEST_gep40_smoketest_xconnect_298_1943` and `Fieldbus_Modbus_TCP_821_1702`

How can i improve my script, so it takes the whole text and after the last `_` befor a int, it takes the first number, stores that, and then the next number, like this:

```py
>>>Namearray = SZTEST_gep40_smoketest_xconnect
>>>JinkinsBuild = 298
>>>TestJob = 1943

#Or like this

>>>Namearray = Fieldbus_Modbus_TCP
>>>JinkinsBuild = 298
>>>TestJob = 1943
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [rsplit()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit)

```
files = ['SZTEST_gep40_smoketest_xconnect_298_1943',
         'Fieldbus_EtherNetIP_719_1926',
         'Fieldbus_Modbus_TCP_821_1702']

for file in files:
    print(file.rsplit('_', 2))
```

Output

```
['SZTEST_gep40_smoketest_xconnect', '298', '1943']
['Fieldbus_EtherNetIP', '719', '1926']
['Fieldbus_Modbus_TCP', '821', '1702']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for regex.

```
names = ['Fieldbus_EtherNetIP_719_1926', 'SZTEST_gep40_smoketest_xconnect_298_1943', 'Fieldbus_Modbus_TCP_821_1702']
for name in names:
    match = re.match(r'(.*)_(\d+)_(\d+)$', name)
    if match:
        print(match.groups())
```